# Default view padding

Tags: android, layout, view, padding

I'm just starting to learn android and i had a doubt concerning to view padding. Referring to [What controls the default padding between views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397814/what-controls-the-default-padding-between-views) , Is the padding included in the size we specify to the view ? All help appreciated!

EDIT: Also does a layout add padding to itself by default ?

Comment: show your xml code also

Answer (score 0):

In the question you linked to, the padding is caused by the button's background being a nine-patch and having some transparent borders in it. Since the "padding" is part of the background resource, it is include in the image size and you don't need to do anything to make it show up.

However, if you are creating your own Views, or changing the background or foreground resources of the system provided Widgets, you may want to use the `android:padding*` attributes to specify the various paddings.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'm not sure on what a nine-patch is but i'll look it up now. Can you please answer my question regarding layouts ? Editted my original question with the changes.